# Rotate in edit mode is not reversible

Tags: python, edit-mode, transforms

When I open the following obj file in blender

```
# Blender v2.83.18 OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
o scan
v -4.170000 29.930016 4.589891
v -4.170000 29.940016 4.409892
v -4.060000 30.000023 5.569891
v -4.050000 29.960020 5.389892
v -4.090000 29.970018 5.289891
v -4.050000 29.920019 5.139892
v -4.060000 29.920017 4.989892
v -4.050000 29.890018 4.829892
v -4.120000 29.920017 4.719892
v -4.030000 29.870018 4.629892
v -4.040000 29.870016 4.429892
v -4.050000 29.880014 4.259892
v -4.030000 29.870016 4.149891
v -4.040000 29.880014 4.019892
v -4.040000 29.890015 3.809892
v -4.030000 29.890015 3.629892
v -4.050000 30.040007 2.349891
v -4.050000 30.030008 2.209891
v -4.060000 30.060007 1.939891
v -4.030000 30.050007 1.759891
v -3.960000 30.100023 6.299891
v -3.950000 30.050024 6.149891
v -3.930000 30.010021 5.969892
```

and run this script over and over again:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move()
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=0.2, orient_axis='Y', orient_type='CURSOR', use_accurate=True)
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-0.2, orient_axis='Y', orient_type='CURSOR', use_accurate=True)
```

while starting in **edit mode** the resulting vertices are shifted. They seem to be rotated back just fine but shifted by a bit.

In **object mode** everything works as expected.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

I wasn't able to reproduce this with the standard blender cube.

I've tested it in blender 2.83.18 and blender 2.93.5 with the same result.

Comment: Apply Transforms - Object Mode, Select object Under the Object menu>Aplly>All Transforms

Comment: Changing to Object mode and doing that doesn't change anything and I also don't get why it should.

Comment: My guess is it's just a stacking of precision error. The default cube has all coordinates of all vertices equal to `1` or `-1` which is only a single digit of precision, so it's hard to rotate it by such an angle, that the coordinates will be rounded in such a way, that after rotating back it won't be exactly `1` or `-1`. In case of an object, `0.2` rotation is again only a single digit of precision, and so it's unlikely to get a corruption of `x + 0.2 - 0.2 != x`.

Comment: And in object mode it works because the object stores the rotation and then it gets basically just rotated back? I've also tried to move the the cube vertices to a different spot but wasn't able to replicate it. It's just weird that it immediately shows a visible change for just one rotate and back.

Comment: floating point accuracy maybe. but what are you trying to do?

Comment: In object mode you could get a similar problem, however, I don't think you can have such value `y` that `x + y - y != x`. In case of rotation, there's more math involved and apparently it's asymmetrical. Perhaps even a bug and it could be symmetrical? For example, `3.0 + 0.0000000000000003 == 3.0000000000000004`, but also `3.0000000000000004 - 0.0000000000000003 == 3.0`.

Comment: @lemon during some calculation I rotate and translate some points but in the end I want to move them back including some curves that I calculated during the process. The rotate back functionality seemed to be simple but unfortunately this "bug" crossed my way. I'm sure when I rotate them by applying a transformation matrix to the points and back the error won't be that big. I can immediately see the difference without zooming in too much.

Comment: One coordinate is: `(-4.167486190795898, 29.92401695251465, 4.4098920822143555)` the other `(-4.169715881347656, 29.92439079284668, 4.4098920822143555)`  which is a change in the third decimal.

Comment: Maybe try with matrix manipulation instead of blender operators ?

Comment: Yeah still trying to figure out how to do that @Gorgious :D